# NLA Editor: Tweaking an action while also playing ALL other strips and actions?

Tags: nla-editor

I'm animating a guy playing a guitar. Several actions are playing at the same time:

STRIP 1: ACTION 1: General body movements (moving the guitar around, swaying, etc)

STRIP 2: ACTION 2: Hands playing riff 1

STRIP 3: ACTION 3: Hands playing riff 2

STRIP 4: ACTION 4: Face bones animation

The reason it's set up like this is because the riffs are repetitive and playing at different times throughout the song, while some sections (the solo, the sung parts) are unique, so it makes sense to use NLA.

The problem comes in when I'm trying to tweak (edit) an action in any strip below STRIP 2 (the second topmost strip). **While tweaking it, only this action is playing, while all the rest are ignored.**

For example, when tweaking the face animation action (strip 4), this results in the whole rest of the body being stuck in a weird default pose, not animating like I want it to. I've noticed that for some reason only the first 2 topmost strips/actions can be displayed playing at the same time while tweaking one of them.

How do I make it so I can see ALL the strips while tweaking a bottom strip?